# How to simulate a condition which is like UIPanGestureRecognizer's callback function

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I made a function to handle a complex layout . The function is driven by  UIPanGestureRecognizer's callback function. Fortunately，it works perfectly.
Now,I want to creat a new active method to call the function. It comes the question ：can I simulate a condition to call the function without any modification?

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:myParentView];
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x+translation.x,self.center.y);
    isToLeft = (translation.x<0) ? YES : NO;
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(midMoveViewMove: transX:isToLeft:)]) {
        [self.delegate midMoveViewMove:CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y)
                                transX:translation.x
                              isToLeft:isToLeft];
    }
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:myParentView];}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are your trying to achieve something like simulation of the pangesture using touches or something else?